# What is the probability of one person winning a new car with one entry packet?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Looking at an A-Level Book (A Concise Course in A-Level Statistics), I came across a question which I cannot figure out. The questions is:

> To enter a cereal competition, competitors have to choose the 8 most important features of a new car, from a possible 12 features, then list the 8 in order of preference. Each cereal packet entry form contains space for 5 entries. A correct entry wins a new car. What is the probability of one person winning a new car with one entry packet?

My logic would be that to win with one selection it would be 1 / permutation(12,8) and hence with 5 entries it would 5 multiplied by this number.

However looking at the solution the probability is 2.5E-7 I cannot understand how this is the case.

Comment: I don't know if the process of this game is clear for you. It is not clear for me. Probably some clarification is needed.

Comment: $\frac{5}{^{12}P_{8}}\approx 2.5\times 10^{-7}$

Comment: What makes an entry "correct"? The question talks about "importance" and "preference", both of which are subjective. However subjective biases are commonly shared over large groups (e.g., "has working engine" would likely be much more popular than "has fuzzy dice hanging from mirror"), so if the objective is to match the contest-runner's choice, there would likely be a bias for some entries and against others, instead of all possible entries having the same chance. The question is very poorly worded.